# Renaming a file, while adding +01 at the end

Tags: powershell

I am currently taking a CSV File and renaming it to a .txt file. I Currently save the name as `yyyymmdd.txt`, I am trying to check the folder for the txt file and append "`-01`" to the file. (`yyyy-mm-dd-01.txt`,`..-02`,`..-03`,..) each time the script checks it should add 01 to the file. My current problem is the file gets renamed to `yyyymmdd.txt01` and if it checks it just puts `yyyymmdd.txt11`

I've tried a few ways, but have failed to succeed.

```
$filevalue = 'C:\test\test_notepad.csv'
$path = 'C:\test\'
$file = 'test.txt'
$file2 = 'test_notepade.csv'
$date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-mm-dd-"
$filename = "$date.txt"
Rename-Item $filevalue $filename
$originalFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\test\text" -Filter *.txt
$x = 1
ForEach ($originalFile in $originalFiles) {
    $x++
    Rename-Item -Path $originalFile.FullName -NewName ($originalFile.Name -replace "^", "1")
}
```

Comment: you want to use the `.BaseName` property, not the `.Name` property. [*grin*]

Comment: #2 How do I make sure it goes from 01 to 02 etc? without making it 0101 ?

Comment: grab the last two characters, coerce them into an `[int]`, then increment it. last, stick it on the end of the remaining `.BaseName`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

here's a way to do what you want. the stuff before the `ForEach-Object` is to make a testing file - and to ensure there is only the one since i didn't include any error checking. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- iterates thru 17 times to test the code
- gets the file info
- splits the `.BaseName` on the unique `_` character
- grabs the last item in the resulting array
- converts that number string to an `[int]`
- increments it
- pads it to two digits
- replaces the old seq number in the file name with the new one
- renames the file

here's the code ...

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'

# delete any existing test file
$Null = Remove-Item -Path "$env:TEMP\$($Today)_*.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# create a file to work with
$Null = New-Item -Path $env:TEMP -Name "$($Today)_07.txt" -ItemType File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# pretend to access the listing 17 times
1..17 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $FileInfo = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -Filter "$Today*.txt"
        $OldSeqNumber = $FileInfo.BaseName.Split('_')[-1]
        $NewSeqNumber = '{0:D2}' -f ([int]$OldSeqNumber + 1)

        $NewFileName = $FileInfo.Name.Replace("_$OldSeqNumber", "_$NewSeqNumber")

        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $FileInfo.FullName -NewName $NewFileName
        }
```

original file name = `2019-05-07_07.txt`
last new file name = `2019-05-07_24.txt`